# Display uploaded file using Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have some code written that takes a single image file from index.html through an HTML form, adds a border to it using the gm module and saves it on the server. Now I'm trying to find a way to display it back to the user, preferably on the same page it was uploaded.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/output'))

const upload = multer({
    dest: 'temp/'
  }); 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.post('/', upload.single('file-to-upload'), (req, res) => {
  var temp = req.file['path'];
  var output = __dirname + '/output/' + req.file['filename'] + '.png'
  console.log(req.file)
  gm(temp)
  .setFormat('png')
  .resizeExact(512,512)
  .composite(__dirname + '/masks/border.png')
  .write(temp, function() {
    gm(512, 512, 'none')
    .fill(temp)
    .drawCircle(256, 256, 256, 0)
    .write(output, function(err) {
       console.log(err || 'done');
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Write your uploaded file in your public folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your Express route never responds, it leaves the connection to the browser hanging. The key here is to respond with an HTML document. The laziest way to do that is (continuing at the end of your function):

```
.write(output, function(err) {
  console.log(err || 'done');
  return res.send(`
    <title>My Image Is Neat!</title>
    <h1>My Image Is Neat!</h1>
    <img src="/${req.file['filename'] + '.png'}" />
  `);
});
```

`/${req.file['filename'] + '.png'}` works because your use of express.static is mapping the /output folder into the root. You might want to add `/uploads` as the first argument so that the paths begin with `/uploads` and are less easily confused with other things.

As for including it in the page from which they uploaded it, you can write a function to send a similar backticked string for the original form, or you can get a little less lazy and use a templating language like Pug or Nunjucks to break these out to separate files.

Your approach so far implies you are not creating a single-page application with React, Vue, etc. but rather building old-school HTML forms. But if your real goals involve those frameworks you will need to change your approach to create an API rather than render pages.